# Which app can add a shortcut to send SMS to my homescreen in Android 5.1.1?

Tags: android, widget

Apparently the stock *Contact* app's widget to send an SMS to a specific content from the homescreen has been removed by Samsung on the Galaxy S6 in Android 5.1.1 [as discussed in this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137246/why-is-there-no-direct-message-widget-on-my-galaxy-s6-stock).

**Is there an app that allows adding this kind of shortcut for a specific contact to directly view and send SMS?**

Replacing the messenger app would be fine as long as the SMS database does not get corrupted and can later be moved back to the default messenger if the now-missing feature comes back.

Comment: Just a tip: Tasker allow creation of scene (UI; no programming needed). You can easily create a scene and create its shortcut on home screen. The scene would have a field to provide contact's number (or pre-selected) and other field to provide content for SMS. You can then create a button or something to send the SMS.